# LiveSearch in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nested

In the example shown, the name of the country is searched for. This is located in the first level of the json object.
How can I search for a string that is one level down?
As an example in `altSpellings`?

```
[{
"name":"Afghanistan", 
"altSpellings":["AF","Afġānistān"],
"region":"Asia",
}]
```

If i change the line in the filter like so: `return place.altSpellings.match(regex)`
i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: place.altSpellings.match is not a function`

```js
const countries = [];
fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => countries.push(...json));

function searchCountries(wordToSearch, countries) {
  return countries.filter(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(wordToSearch, 'gi');
    return place.name.match(regex)
  })
}

function liveSearch() {
  if (this.value.length) {
    const searchResult = searchCountries(this.value, countries);

    const searched = searchResult.map(item => {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const name = item.name.replace(regex, `<b>${this.value}</b>`)
      const altSpellings = item.altSpellings

      return `<div>${name}<br>${altSpellings}<br><br></div>`;

    }).join('');

    results.innerHTML = searched;
  } else {
    results.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const results = document.querySelector('.results');
search.addEventListener('keyup', liveSearch);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Ajax Search countries</h1>
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search any country here" />
  <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this

```js
const countries = [];
fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => countries.push(...json));

function searchCountries(wordToSearch, countries) {
  return countries.filter(({name, altSpellings}) => {
    let isMatched = false
    const regex = new RegExp(wordToSearch, 'gi');
    const namesArr = [name, ...altSpellings]
    namesArr.forEach(v => {
     if (v.match(regex)) {
       isMatched = true
     }
    })
 
    return isMatched
  })
}

function liveSearch() {
  if (this.value.length) {
    const searchResult = searchCountries(this.value, countries);

    const searched = searchResult.map(item => {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const name = item.name.replace(regex, `<b>${this.value}</b>`)
      const altSpellings = item.altSpellings.map(v => v.replace(regex,`<b>${v}</b>`))
      return `<div>${name}<br>${altSpellings}<br><br></div>`;

    }).join('');

    results.innerHTML = searched;
  } else {
    results.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const results = document.querySelector('.results');
search.addEventListener('keyup', liveSearch);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Ajax Search countries</h1>
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search any country here" />
  <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but with your code just the string in the search results in `altSpelling` will be maked with bold. But the results still remain on the `name` in the object.

Comment: sorry, forget add to search func. I'm update my answer

Comment: Great, thank you a lot. Just one more thing... Is there a way to show just the result entries of ?altSpelling` ? (Example: Searchstring "ax" -> output: AX,Aaland,Aland,Ahvenanmaa, wanted output: AX)

Comment: you must filter and compact in map `const altSpellings = item.altSpellings.map(v => v.replace(regex,`<b>${v}</b>`)). When matched return `v.replace`, when not matched return null
`